# Skip wizard page(step) based on a value

Tags: acumatica

We use a wizard control with 4 wizard pages. 
On the first step a user choose an option from dropdown element.
According to the value we may need to skip third step of wizard.
How should I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the index of the next page for PXWizard, you should fisrt subscribe to the **OnSelectNextPage** event in  **.aspx* or **.aspx.cs* code behind file:

```
<px:PXWizard ID="wizard" runat="server" DataMember="wizardSummary" 
    OnSelectNextPage="wizard_OnSelectNextPage" CaptionVisible="True"
    Width="100%" Height="300px" SkinID="Flat" AutoSize="True" >
    <NextCommand Target="ds" Command="wizardNext" />
    <AutoSize Enabled="true" />
    <Pages>
        ...
    </Pages>
</px:PXWizard>
```

The second step is to assign the next wizard page index to the **NextPage** property of the **PXWizardSelectPageEventArgs** class within a previously defined **OnSelectNextPage** event handler:

```
public partial class Page_XXXXXXXX : PX.Web.UI.PXPage
{
    ...

    protected void wizard_OnSelectNextPage(object sender, PXWizardSelectPageEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateBAccountMassProcess graph = ds.DataGraph as UpdateBAccountMassProcess;
        if (graph == null) return;

        if (myCondition != true)
        {
            e.NextPage = 2;
        }
    }
}
```